# Allow User Role To Schedule Content As Different User

Tags: users

I am creating a "submitter" user role which should be allowed to post articles as different users - what permission do I need to set for this on the "Permission" page under "People" to grant access to the "author" field?

If thats not possible is there a module for it?

Answer (score 0):

That would be *Administer Content*. Be careful with this, because the permission provides a lot more than simply control over the node Author identity.

The alternative would be the [Masquerade](https://drupal.org/project/masquerade) module, which would allow the user to pretend they were a different user, and post content as that user. A little more involved for the posting user, but safer for your site.

Answer (score 0):

[Override Node Options](https://drupal.org/project/override_node_options) module is what you need :)

> The Override Node Options module allows permissions to be set to each field
>   within the Authoring information and Publishing options field sets on the node
>   form. It also allows selected field sets to be set as collapsed and / or collapsible."